# RSpec automatically runs rake db:test:prepare

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

My spec_helper.rb

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start 'rails'

# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'fakeweb'
require 'rack_session_access/capybara'
require 'sidekiq/testing'
require 'rake'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.include Capybara::DSL
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller

  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before :suite do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
    Rails.cache.clear
    $redis.flushdb
    Sidekiq::Worker.clear_all

    if example.metadata[:sidekiq] == :fake
      Sidekiq::Testing.fake!
    elsif example.metadata[:sidekiq] == :inline
      Sidekiq::Testing.inline!
    elsif example.metadata[:type] == :acceptance
      Sidekiq::Testing.inline!
    else
      Sidekiq::Testing.fake!
    end
  end

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"

end

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
include Warden::Test::Helpers
Warden.test_mode!
```

Issue: RSpec automatically runs rake db:test:prepare (or clone), but the trouble is that I have stored procedures in my migrations than can't be copied directly from schema.rb. So, are there way to disable it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using stored procedures or other database-specific features in your migrations, you should change the `config.active_record.schema_format` setting to `:sql` [as explained in this document](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#types-of-schema-dumps). Otherwise the only way to set up a clean copy of your database would be to run all your migrations in sequence, which is not a sustainable approach. Once you resolve that issue, your test runs should work perfectly fine.